# Subsetting a data.frame, sometimes want all values (wild card *)

Tags: r, subset, wildcard

I want to subset at data frame, within a function as such this code, by passing it a variable value to pass after the "=="

```
inputdata = CensoredOriginal[CensoredOriginal$Area==5, ]
```

Sometimes I want a subset, and sometimes I want the whole set, i.e. when

```
inputdata = CensoredOriginal[CensoredOriginal$Area==*, ]
```

But R doesn't like my use of the wildcard to mean "any value" or alternatively the whole set.  What am I doing wrong, or is there a way to use a wildcard to select?

Comment: You can use `grepl` i.e. `CensoredOriginal[grepl("\\d+", CensoredOriginal$Area),]` or may be use `%in%` instead of `==` i.e. `CensoredOriginal[CensoredOriginal$Area %in% c(5, 10, 15), ]`

Answer (score 0):

If this happens within a function, it means 5/* is either an argument of the function or is set somewhere before your subset. In that case, I suggests testing for it:

```
myfunc <- function(x, ...){
  ...
  if(x != "*") {
    inputdata = CensoredOriginal[CensoredOriginal$Area == x, ]
  } else {
    inputdata = CensoredOriginal
  }
  ...
```

}

Then, `myfunc(5)` will subset, but `myfunc("*")` will not.